# How to delay Picasso image loading?

Tags: android, imageview, android-animation, picasso, shared-element-transition

I have implemented a shared element activity transition animation between MainActivity (GridView) and DetailActivity. When item is clicked, the image in Grid item will zoom-in to become the background image in DetailActivity. I have made the transition very smooth by saving the image on the MainActivity into a file, then use it as placeholder image in DetailActivity before the higher quality image is downloaded via picasso. When picasso finished its task the higher quality image will replace the placeholder one very neatly.

Code from onCreateView() in DetailActivityFragment.java

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) mRootview.findViewById(R.id.movie_poster);
try {
    // Prepare "InterimPoster" jpeg file to be placeholder image
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(c.openFileInput("InterimPoster"));
    Picasso.with(c).load("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780" + mMovieInfo[2])
            .placeholder(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap))
            .fit()
            .centerCrop()
            .noFade()
            .into(iv);

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

As for animation, I implement it like in the link here step 1-3 https://guides.codepath.com/android/Shared-Element-Activity-Transition

However, sometimes there's flicker when the higher quality image finished download before the transition animation is completed. The zooming-in image will be replaced with new image while moving which is an unpleasant animation.

So I wonder how can I fix this flicker? One thing I can think of is to delay the image download because I already have lower quality image as a placeholder. How can I do that?

[Here the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GTH1JIa-3HE).
Usually, on my test device it's smooth 80% of the time, but luckily in this video it flicker most of the time.

Comment: I think the flicker is because of noFade(). Try removing that.

Comment: No, I intentionally put in noFade() because otherwise it will always flicker even if the loading finished after the animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I have found a way to delay Picasso image loading (or any other task). It's very simple really with the use of [Handler and Runnable](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Repeating-Periodic-Tasks#handler).

Now my code looks like this. The image replacement is pretty smooth in any case now.

```
    // Set Background Poster in Try-catch in case file cannot be open
    try {
        // Get/Prepare "InterimPoster" jpeg file to be placeholder image
        final ImageView iv = (ImageView) mRootview.findViewById(R.id.movie_poster);
        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(c.openFileInput("InterimPoster"));
        final Drawable lowResPoster = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
        iv.setImageDrawable(lowResPoster);

        // Download higher resolution image with 0.8 sec delay to avoid load complete before
        // animation finishes (causing some flicker/overflow image problem).
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Picasso.with(c).load("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780" + mMovieInfo[2])
                        // still need placeholder here otherwise will flash of white image
                        .placeholder(lowResPoster)
                        .error(lowResPoster)
                        .fit()
                        .centerCrop()
                        .noFade() // without this image replacement will not be smooth
                        .into(iv);
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 800);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

what's animation ? load image while animation end

```
 TranslateAnimation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0,1.5f,0,1.5f);
    translateAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
               //load image when animation end
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
```

and

```
  LayoutTransition.TransitionListener transitionListener = new LayoutTransition.TransitionListener() {
        @Override
        public void startTransition(LayoutTransition transition, ViewGroup container, View view, int transitionType) {

        }

        @Override
        public void endTransition(LayoutTransition transition, ViewGroup container, View view, int transitionType) {
                    //load image when animation end
        }
    };
```

Comment: I am using the animation as in https://guides.codepath.com/android/Shared-Element-Activity-Transition .. I don't know how to use translateAnimation with that. Can you advise, please?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

**First use picasso normally to load placeholder into the imageview**

```
iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

**Then use SharedElement Listener like this**

```
Transition sharedElementEnterTransition = getWindow().getSharedElementEnterTransition();sharedElementEnterTransition.addListener(new TransitionListenerAdapter() {
     @Override
      public void onTransitionEnd(android.support.transition.Transition transition) {
                super.onTransitionEnd(transition);
         Picasso.with(c).load("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780" + mMovieInfo[2])
        .placeholder(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap))
        .fit()
        .centerCrop()
        .noFade()
        .into(iv);
       }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

To delay some process, you can use Handler().

Example.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            // write your codes here.. this  will delay 2 seconds...
           startActivity(new Intent(this,MySecondActivity.class); 


        }
    },2000);
```